# Update BIOS latitude e6530 don't progress after automatically restart

Tags: laptop, bios, dell-latitude

Hello Guys I have a Dell Latitude E6530 and my currently version of BIOS is A11.

Now I need to update it to new version A22.

I download BIOS "E6530A22.exe" and run it all it's fin, but after system restart automatically to progress update. Don't progress, after restart automatically it run windows.

Any solution of this problem

Comment: Try downloading the BIOS file from the Dell support site and trying again. The process as you describe looks correct.

Comment: I download it from dell site. I try old BIOS and new BIOS nothing work. but I see problem after boot by F12, I don't see BIOS Flash Update option in listed, look in this photo. https://www.dell.com/community/image/serverpage/image-id/64858iE45C3117E3C645F4/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999

Comment: You do not want to brick your machine, so contact Dell Support and get them to help you.

Comment: There are 10 bios versions after A11, try installing one older first, like A14>>>click "older versions" on this page>>>>https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-e6530/drivers

Comment: If that works, try A18 next if that works, then A22

Comment: Have you followed the [Installation instructions](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-yu/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=vtvjj)? There are several methods listed, so you could for example use the BIOS F12 method. Ensure your download is correct by its checksum value.

Comment: Guys I Try all method but nothing work, and Try all Version of BIOS old and new but nothing work, and the BIOS F12 method no listed BIOS Flash Update option why? if the are any laptop don't have update BIOS, this is BIOS versions https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-e6530/drivers

Comment: If you'd really tried "all method" then the problem would be fixed. Please list each thing you've tried, using the EDIT button to add this to the question.

Comment: I try all method look, this is my problem: https://youtu.be/Tw6txLT99wk